# How can I create a base component in Ionic project

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I handle authentication in my `Ionic` app with a `Service`. I would like to have `View` separated from `Service`. I have a function in `auth` service to fetch user. If user is not available in memory or database, I want the user to be redirected to `Login` page. This `getUser` function is used in different components.

`getUser(){
    if (this.user) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.user) ;
    } else {
      return this.storage.get('user').then( (user) => {
        if (user){
          this.user = user;
          return user
        } else {
        \\ way to prompt login page here.
        }
      })
      .catch( this.handleError )
    }
  }`

I would like to have something like a base component to handle login page push when `user` is not available. As far as I know angular doesn't support component inheritance. How can I achieve the functionality ? What I was thinking was a `Subject` emitted when no user is available. And the base component `subscribe` to this subject . How can I achieve this in `Ionic` ?